# Dividing the pentagon

Tags: mathematics, geometry

It is easy to divide an equilateral triangle into three equal, though not equilateral, triangles.

[image: Triangle divided]

---

It is even simpler to divide a square into four equal squares.
[image: Square divided]

---

The difficult part is, **whether you can divide a regular pentagon into five equal pentagons**?

Note:

> `Equal` means, equal in area.

Comment: can we have 1 extra pentagon in the end or the question is about exactly 5?

Comment: If all are equal in terms of area, then I'm ok with it :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Easy, the only definition of a pentagon is that is must have 5 sides :)

> [image: splitted pentagon]

You could replicate it for orders 7,9, 11 and so on.
(Just figured it won't work for even numbers)

Comment: +1 but how can i believe that their areas are equal

Comment: Haha, I was just in the process of drawing exactly this, then saw this answer appear. Nice one.

Comment: @manshu if you add 5 points somewhere on the straight lines from the centre to the 5 vertices (doesn't matter where, somewhere near the middle), then rotate all 5 of those elbow points around the centre, then all 5 shapes will be identical (and therefore have the same area).

Comment: @manshu because all of the areas are symmetrical - if all the red lines are drawn in the exact same way and are simply $72\unicode{xb0}$ rotations of each other

Comment: It works perfectly. Actually, many would think of a convex polygon to begin with, that would be confusing.

Comment: Yeah I thought pentagones had to be of equal sides. Had to look it up! +1 good one

Comment: Your answer was quick, I was about to sleep, just saw it... Good night everyone, it was a great day puzzling ^_^

Comment: "Just figured it won't work for even numbers" - then you make the cuts in the middle of the original polygon's edges, like the example with the square, instead of at the vertices.

Comment: This reminds me of the recent [paper on tilings of the disc](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03794) that was reported in the media as ["crazy new ways to cut a pizza."](http://gizmodo.com/mathematicians-have-found-crazy-new-ways-to-cut-pizza-i-1751776752)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert that was fun ^_^